# Javascript Regex - capture everything except C-style comments

Tags: javascript, regex

The problem: I'm trying to style certain keywords (e.g. "function") within the content of a code-tag, excluding those keywords from the C-style comments that appear in that content. 
Solution: I believe that a match of the innerHTML-string of the code-tag against a Regex-pattern, that would exclude the C-style comments could do the job...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait... you want to parse (inner)HTML with regex? Is this for something important / security critical?

Comment: have a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter and see how they do it

Answer (score 1):

C-style comments can be nested and are therefore not suitable for a regular expression.

Matching an unnested C-style comment is simple:

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

Allowing one level of nesting results in:

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*+(?:/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*+\*/(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*+)*+.*?\*/
```

(taken from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)'s library). Try to imagine what happens if you allow more.

I understand your question as "Is it possible for a regular expression to match a block of text that is outside of C-style comments?" - this would be even more complex than this. Imagine a string like `"This is used to start a C comment: /*"`. Furthermore, if you still wanted to try this, you'd need lookbehind which JavaScript doesn't support.